# Why cmake shows message when it should not?

Tags: cmake

Fltk is found, but test not passed, why?

## define a simple macro

```
macro(assert TEST COMMENT)
  message(${TEST})
  if(NOT ${TEST})
    message("Assertion failed: ${COMMENT}")
  endif()
endmacro()

# use the macro
find_library(FLTK_LIB fltk)
assert(${FLTK_LIB} "Unable to find library fltk")
```

Output:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfltk.so
Assertion failed: Unable to find library fltk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( NOT ${TEST} )
```

You are *expanding* `TEST` here, i.e. you are basically saying...

```
if( NOT "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfltk.so" )
```

[CMake docs on `if`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html) state that:

> `if(<string>)`
>
> A quoted string always evaluates to false unless:
>
> - The string's value is one of the true constants [...]

So the default is false, and true constants are:

> [...] 1, ON, YES, TRUE, Y, or a non-zero number.

Your string is neither, so it's false, so your assertion always triggers.

If you were in a `function`, the solution would be to just write...

```
if( NOT TEST )
```

...because that wouldn't test the string, but the variable, on which the documentation states...

> `if(<variable>)`
>
> True if given a variable that is defined to a value that is not a false constant. False otherwise, including if the variable is undefined.

So the default is true, unless your variable is undefined or one of the false constants...

> 0, OFF, NO, FALSE, N, IGNORE, NOTFOUND, the empty string, or ends in the suffix -NOTFOUND

Unfortunately you have written your assertion as a macro, not a function. Unfortunately, because...

> Note that macro arguments are not variables.

At which point I, personally, heed my C/C++ programmer genes of "macros are evil" and would suggest you turn your `assert()` into a `function` and write `if( NOT TEST )`.